# Combine two rows of strings in a specific order using formulae

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in on sheet like this:

```
Barbie
HeMan
Superman
Batman
```

and another column in another sheet like this:

```
Madrid
Barcelona
Athens
London
Timbuktu
```

I need output as below (preferably two columns, alternatively space separated in one):

```
Barbie Madrid
Barbie Barcelona
Barbie Athens
Barbie London
Barbie Timbuktu
HeMan Madrid
HeMan Barcelona
HeMan Athens
HeMan London
HeMan Timbuktu
```

How can this be done using Excel formulae please?

Comment: Is the desired output in a single column, space-separated, or in two columns?

Comment: Preferably two clumns or in a single coumn seperated by a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes the following:

- Data with “Super Heroes” is located in `Sheet1` at `B6:B9` *(adjust ranges in formulas as required)*
- Data with “Cities” is located in `Sheet2` at `B6:B10` *(adjust ranges in formulas as required)*
- Data combined is located in `Sheet3` starting at `B6` *(adjust ranges in formulas as required)*

Enter this formula in `Sheet3` at `B6` and copy till last record (i.e. ~ `B31`)

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( Sheet1!$B$6:$B$9,
ROUNDUP( ROWS( B$6:B6 ) / ROWS( Sheet2!$B$6:$B$10 ), 0 ) ), "" )
```

and this formula in `Sheet3` at `C6` and copy till last record (i.e. ~ `C31`)

```
=IF( EXACT( B6, "" ), "", INDEX( Sheet2!$B$6:$B$10,
1 + MOD( -1 + ROWS( C$6:C6 ), ROWS( Sheet2!$B$6:$B$10 ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first and second of your lists are in column A of Sheet1 and Sheet2 respectively, and that there are no other entries in those columns apart from the data you wish to be returned, then, in cell A1 of your worksheet chosen to house the results:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A)*COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),"",INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,CEILING(ROWS($1:1)/COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A),1)))`

And in B1:

`=IF(A1="","",INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,1+MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A))))`

Copy both down until you start to get blanks for the results.

Regards

Comment: hello XOR LX. My excel session crashes as my sheet 1 has 1800 values and Sheet 2 has 38 values. Am I missing something here. It says no memory.

Comment: If there were nothing else but those 1838 values and my formulas then this alone would not cause any issues. To how many rows did you copy my formulas? Not to the very end of the worksheet, I hope?